# MongoDB (mongoose) pushing into arrays is ignoring properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User Schema that looks like this:

```
reputation: [
{
  voter_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
},
{
  score: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
},
{
  comment: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 100,
  },
},
{
  voted_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
},
],
```

Whenever I try to push an object into this array like this

```
User.updateOne(
  { id: user.id },
  {
    $push: {
      reputation: {
        voter_id: interaction.user.id,
        score: rating,
        comment,
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Only the first property of the object to push, here **voter_id** is set in the database, even though the other values are not undefined.

The object stored in the database looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61478043630ef626f50c9c2b"), "reputation" : [ { "voter_id" : "214772155114717184", "_id" : ObjectId("61478060630ef626f50c9c7c") } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

The properties are missing. For this example score was 1 and comment "test". Whats the problem here?

Comment: That schema declaration looks odd.  Did you intend to have an array of single-field objects?

Comment: No, I want all properties of the object to be stored not just a single one.

Comment: In the schema you show, the array is 4 separate objects each with 1 field.  Try defining 1 object with 4 fields.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The array notation is what tricks into making the items within separate, should be a single object:

```js
reputation: [
{
  voter_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  score: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  comment: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 100,
  },
  voted_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
}
]
```